# How do I clone a project to make a second project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clone

My first project is a rails app written in Cloud9 and pushed to bit bucket and heroku in production.

How do I make an exact clone of this project so that I can rename it and begin working on a second project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html) tutorial you should:

1. Navigate to the repository in Bitbucket.
2. Click the **Clone** button.
3. Copy the clone command (either the SSH format or the HTTPS).

   If you are using the SSH protocol, ensure sure your public key is in Bitbucket and loaded on the local system to which you are cloning.
4. Launch a terminal window.
5. Change to the local directory where you want to clone your repository.
6. Paste the command you copied from Bitbucket, for example:

   ```
   $ git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com:7999/PROJ/repo.git
   ```

Comment: the changes i made in the clone were pushed to the same git repository. i tried to create a new repository but something went wrong. does something in the code need to be changed to make it possible to push to a new repository after cloing? thanks.

Comment: Take a look here: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

It's easy finding these kind of information on Internet. Just google it.